# WordPress SET Primary key when importing from CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone help help me with the sql query that might help me to get the result:
I like to set my own post id when creating post, it might be wp_insert_post or creating from a csv file.

Basically I will import some woocommerce product containing product ID.

I have tried with sql query but that is not a proper solution because the post id is related to many table.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.